# CMFormatDescription.h Unknown type name 'AudioFormatListItem'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode13

I have a very old iOS project that i'm trying to get back on the app store, using XCode 13.0.

When compiling it is giving me errors from within AVFoundation as in CMFormatDescription.h has an error

```
CMFormatDescription.h Unknown type name 'AudioFormatListItem'
```

Tracing the error back from AVFoundation it it comes down to the header where I actually import AVFoundation in a header file of one of my classes.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

The project has AVFoundation and CoreMedia frameworks imported in the build phases so I'm not sure why it would be giving me compiler errors for code within the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up opening a code support case with Apple Support. The issue came down to having a folder in my build folder called CoreAudio.framework . That somehow ended up in a folder with all my classes which was contained in my compile path.

Deleting this folder and its contents allowed the build to complete successfully.